# How to assign uid in "users" table with imported users?

Tags: users, migrations, entities

I am using Drupal 7.

I am using the Migrate module to migrate a list of users from an external user database table into the Drupal "users" table. The problem is that the Drupal "users" table has a numerical "uid" field, which does not exist in my external database users table.

Could someone please tell me of a way to assign a unique uid to the users table everytime I map a row using Migrate?

For example, right now I have, in the "users" database:

```
0
1 root ...
//external users start here
2 user1 ...
3 user2 ...
4 user3 ...
```

Essentially I have would like to start at 2 and continue for each user I migrate over to the "users" table.

More specifically, how I would modify/add a line to the following so that the code can auto generate unique ID's starting from 2? Would the following code be a viable option? If so, where would be the appropriate place to update $counter?

```
$counter = 2;
$this->addFieldMapping('uid', '$counter');
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

If I were to use the following SQL statement to do the user migration, would it be a good idea? If it is also a viable option, how might be able to create unique "uid" for insertion into the "users" table?

```
INSERT INTO users (uid, name, mail,pass,...) SELECT uid, oldusername, email, md5(clear_password),... FROM old_users_table;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to show your code. Migrate has a specific destination class for users which should take stuff like uid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting data directly into Drupal tables is generally a bad idea (until you are familiar enough with the database schema to know what you're doing). For programmatically inserting users there are functions like [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) and [drupal_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) that you can use.

As for generating the unique `uid`: if you can't just provide incremental values in the data insertion loop then you might be able to use the following code instead (copied from user_save() function):

```
$account->uid = db_next_id(db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField());
```

I'm not familiar with the Migrate module so I don't have more specific advice to offer currently, but the above info and links should be helpful.

Comment: dooshta, thanks for the comment. Could you please show me some code on how I might be able to "provide incremental values in the data insertion loop"? I currently have "MyProjectMigration extends Migration" and in there I have "$this->addFieldMapping('uid', '$uid_counter');" I don't know how to update the $uid_counter value nor do I have a loop? Am I missing something? Even if I remove the "uid" mapping, my Migration does not appear under admin/content/migration, would you happen to know why? Sorry, but this is a little frustrating first time with Migration.

Comment: Do you need to use the Migrate module for this task? If it's a simple one time user import it might be easier to write a custom script. I can't really answer your questions since I haven't worked with the Migrate module myself (it looks pretty complicated to get started with as well). If you need to use the module then you should check out the `BeerUserMigration` class in beer.inc that ships with it, read the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/415260) and try to create a basic working example for yourself which you can then slowly expand to get the necessary end-result.